# Making a sublist out of a list of lists

Tags: list, prolog

I'm trying to make a sublist out of a list of lists in gprolog.  Say I have a list like this:

```
List = [[q,1,3], [q,2,7], [r,3,2], [r,8,7]]
```

I want to make a sublist of just the elements that start with 'q'.

I tried

`delete([r,_,_],List, NewList)`

but it doesn't seem to work.  I'm sure I'm missing something simple but I'm new to gprolog and am not too familiar with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution just checks if a list starts with 'q'

```
f([], []).
f([[q|X]|T1], [[q|X]|T2]) :- !,  f(T1, T2).
f([_|T], X) :- f(T,X).
```

I case you want something more flexible, similar to what you tried, I would do something like this:

```
pick(_, [], []).
pick(P, [[P|X]|T1], [[P|X]|T2]) :- !,  pick(P, T1, T2).
pick(P, [_|T], X) :- pick(P,T,X).
```

so that

```
?- pick(r, [[q,1,3], [q,9,7], [r,3,2], [r,8,7]], Z).
  Z = [[r, 3, 2], [r, 8, 7]] .

?- pick(q, [[q,1,3], [q,9,7], [r,3,2], [r,8,7]], Z).
  Z = [[q, 1, 3], [q, 9, 7]] .
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `findall/3`:

```
findall([q,A,B], member([q,A,B], List), Sublist)
```

If you want to generalize a little:

```
sublist_starting_with(E, List, Sublist) :-
    findall([E,A,B], member([E,A,B], List), Sublist).
```

Answer (score 0):

I have attached my approach below. Iterate through the list until it's empty. If 'q' is present in the head then add that to a list. If not present do nothing keep iterating.

```
head(H,[H|_]).

sublist1([],[]).
sublist1([H|T],[H|Z]):- member(q,H) , head(q,H) , sublist1(T,Z).
sublist1([H|T],Z):- member(q,H) , \+head(q,H) , sublist1(T,Z).
sublist1([H|T],Z):- \+member(q,H) , sublist1(T,Z).
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| ?- sublist1([[q,1,3], [r,2,7], [r,3,2], [r,8,7]],X).

X = [[q,1,3]] ? ;

no
| ?- sublist1([[q,1,3], [q,2,7], [r,3,2], [r,8,7]],X).

X = [[q,1,3],[q,2,7]] ? ;

no
| ?- sublist1([[q,1,3], [q,2,7], [r,3,2], [q,8,7]],X).

X = [[q,1,3],[q,2,7],[q,8,7]] ? ;

no
?- sublist1([[q,1,3], [r,2,7], [r,q,2], [r,8,7]],X).
X = [[q, 1, 3]] ;
no
```

Hope this is what you were looking for. Hope it helped you.

Comment: For the exact specification of the problem, the solution of is not completely correct. It depends on what exactly the input could look like. It works for the example @SOKD KDOS provided but he also clearly states "start with 'q'". This solution would also include for example a list like [r,q,1], because the member function doesn't care about the position